# Run Excel macro without opening it

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a functionality where in I get CSV file as email attachment. I have to import that CSV file into Excel file, build SSRS report on that Excel file. I have written a macro to import data from CSV into Excel. But I want that Excel file should get populated with CSV data without opening because it is not convenient to open Excel file every time to get refreshed SSRS report. I have written VBS code also to run macro but it is not populating my Excel file.

My Macro:

```
Sub getDataImported()
    Sheet11.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 3).EntireColumn.ClearContents
    MsgBox "Inside Macro"
    With Sheet11.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;D:\Sample SSRS\power View\AlertHistory.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        .Name = "AlertHistory"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

My VBS:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'D:\Sample SSRS\power View\AlertHistory.xlsm'!Module1.getDataImported"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you define "Sheet11" in your code. This should give a compile error since it is not declared? I presume if you tried your code manually, it does not run?
If your sheets name is "Sheet11", than use thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet11") instead of 'Sheet11'.

Answer (score 0):

The way he used Sheet11 is valid if Sheet11 is a [CodeName](http://wellsr.com/vba/excel/worksheet-object/#CodeName) of one of his sheets. I'm assuming the macro getDataImported works fine by itself and it's the .vbs file that's failing? Is the name of your module Module1 and are you sure your .vbs file is saved with the extension .vbs? Does your "Inside Macro" msgbox show up when you execute your .vbs file?

I'm the author of the website where you got this from (wellsr.com), so I'm happy to help. Idk why the link to the [original source](http://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/run-macro-without-opening-excel-using-vbscript/) page was edited out.

Comment: Thanks wellsr. I think it was not working since It was not saving data. I modified my .vbs code as below and now it is working fine.                              `Dim objXLWb
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objXLWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Sample SSRS\power View\AlertHistory.xlsm")
objExcel.Application.Run "'D:\Sample SSRS\power View\AlertHistory.xlsm'!Module1.getDataImported"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objXLWb.Save
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing`